# When were they married? vs When did they get married?

Tags: difference

Is it possible to say: "When were they married?". Or only "When did they get married?" is the right one?

Or maybe they have the different meaning? There are both sentences on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence "When were they married?" can mean the same as "When did they get married?", but it could also mean something else.

Suppose that two people are not married to each other at present, but they once were married. Someone might ask "When were they married?", and the answer might be "Until five years ago."

So, "When were they married?" can have two different meanings.

"When did they get married?" asks simply when their marriage began.